# Want to change one database row and not all of them

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I want to update one row of my database.

It's an ATM machine where you first enter in a card account number (it saves this number to be used with different forms). Then you enter an amount to deposit. The problem is that it is updating every row instead of the single row that the card is associated with.

Here's the code:

```
    sqlCommandDeposit.Connection.Open();
    sqlCommandDeposit.Parameters["@cardNumber"].Value = Class1.cardNumber;

    using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommandDeposit.ExecuteReader())
    {

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            balanceDB = decimal.Parse(reader["balance"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    sqlCommandDeposit.Connection.Close();
}

decimal depositAmm = Convert.ToDecimal(textDeposit.Text);
balanceDB = balanceDB + depositAmm;

try
{
    sqlDepositupdate.Connection.Open();
    sqlDepositupdate.Parameters["@cardNumber"].Value = Class1.cardNumber;
    sqlDepositupdate.Parameters["@balanceDB"].Value = balanceDB;

    sqlDepositupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("£" + depositAmm + " Successfully Deposited and Deposit Number Saved");
    MessageBox.Show("you have " + "£" + balanceDB + " available");
    buttonClear.Enabled = true;
    buttonExit.Enabled = true;
    buttonMainMenu.Enabled = true;


}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    sqlDepositupdate.Connection.Close();
}
```

And here's my select statement to find out the current balance:

```
SELECT      dbo.Accounts.balance
FROM        dbo.ATMCards 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Accounts ON dbo.ATMCards.accountID = dbo.Accounts.accountID
WHERE       (dbo.ATMCards.cardNumber = @cardNumber)
```

And this is the update statement:

```
UPDATE      dbo.Accounts
SET         balance = @balanceDB
FROM        dbo.ATMCards 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Accounts AS Accounts_1 ON dbo.ATMCards.accountID = Accounts_1.accountID 
CROSS JOIN  dbo.Accounts
WHERE       (dbo.ATMCards.cardNumber = @cardNumber)
```

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of the Cross Join in the Update query. Why do you have that?

```
UPDATE      dbo.Accounts
SET         balance = @balanceDB
FROM        dbo.ATMCards 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Accounts AS Accounts_1 ON dbo.ATMCards.accountID = Accounts_1.accountID 

WHERE       (dbo.ATMCards.cardNumber = @cardNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your update statement is the method of joining the tables, a `CROSS JOIN` joins all of the rows in one table with all of the rows in another, therefore the update will effect all of the rows in the table, despite your `WHERE` clause. `CROSS JOIN` is also known as a Cartesian product.

As it has been suggested you need to revise your update statement.

Comment: True, I think he meant to use CROSS JOIN with a WHERE clause which acts like an INNER JOIN.  The issue is he has used both the INNER JOIN and the CROSS JOIN.  Alternative way to write this with a CROSS JOIN (to intentionally make things complicated): `UPDATE      dbo.Accounts
SET         balance = @balanceDB
FROM        dbo.ATMCards 
CROSS JOIN  dbo.Accounts AS Accounts_1 WHERE (dbo.ATMCards.accountID = Accounts_1.accountID) AND 
(dbo.ATMCards.cardNumber = @cardNumber)`